# VLOOKUP for any member of a comma-separated list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

If I have an array of values each true or false like so:

<kbd>`Foo`</kbd>  <kbd>`TRUE`</kbd> 
<kbd>`Bar`</kbd>  <kbd>`FALSE`</kbd>
<kbd>`Spam`</kbd> <kbd>`FALSE`</kbd>
<kbd>`Egg`</kbd>  <kbd>`TRUE`</kbd> 
<kbd>`Chips`</kbd><kbd>`FALSE`</kbd>

And cells containing a comma-separated list like so:

<kbd>`Foo,Spam,Chips`</kbd>

I want a function that will return `TRUE` if any of the values in the comma-separated list have a value of `TRUE` in the table, like so:

<kbd>`Foo,Spam,Chips`</kbd><kbd>`TRUE`</kbd>  as `Foo` is `TRUE`

<kbd>`Bar,Spam`</kbd>      <kbd>`FALSE`</kbd> as neither `Bar` not `Spam` are `TRUE`

<kbd>`Egg,Foo`</kbd>       <kbd>`TRUE`</kbd>  both `Foo` and `Egg` are `TRUE`, function works with list in any order

Essentially, I want to be able to `VLOOKUP` on every member of a comma-separated list of arbitrary length, and return the logical OR on the results. I assume I'll need to write a macro to do this. My VBA is a little weak though - where would I begin?

Comment: What is the max amount of commas in the cells containing a comma-separated?

Comment: In practise, I don't think I'll ever need more than 5, but arbitrary length would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your table in A1:B5 and the first delimited string for which you wish to perform the check in E1, in F1:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&A$1:A$5&",",","&E1&","))),0+B$1:B$5)>0`

Copy down to give similar results for strings in E2, E3, etc.

Regards

Comment: ...SUMPRODUCT is mysterious and arcane and so very powerful. Thanks, really thought I'd need a macro for that!

Comment: Never heard that function described as "arcane", but kind of like it! And you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If i get the problem correct, you can use a formula like that:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("foo";E1));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("egg";E1)))
```

SEARCH: finds the exact math in the text; and if founds, it returns 1 value
ISNUMBER: returns true or false based on the value inside is a number or not
And
OR: gets the ansver true even if one of the text is inside the list.

Hope it helps!